# Pandas difference between timestamps per row on column level

Tags: pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, timedelta

I have the following dataframe: df

```
                  Date  Type
0  1990-01-01 02:00:00   1
1  1990-01-01 03:00:00   1
2  1990-01-01 04:00:00   1
3  1990-01-01 05:00:00   2
4  1990-01-01 06:00:00   2
5  1990-01-01 07:00:00   2
```

How do I get the timedifference per row on a new column df['dt'] in seconds within column level df['time']? The following works (but not on column level):

```
df['dt'] = (df['Date'] - df['Date'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

How do I get this to work on column level? Ideally, the beginning of a new type should have 0s as time difference.

Comment: your solution gives me the error: ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta. The complete code is:
`import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
data_empty = {}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_empty)
df['HH'] = np.arange(0,10)
start_date ='1990-01-01 00:00:00'
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['HH'], unit='h', origin=start_date)
df['Type'] = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]`

Comment: oops, mea culpa, not tested solution. So added answer, I hope now working correct.

Answer (score 1):

For solution with `shift` subtract values by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with shifted data per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html), replace missing values to `0 Timedeta` and last use [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame() 
df['HH'] = np.arange(0,10) 
start_date ='1990-01-01 00:00:00' 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['HH'], unit='h', origin=start_date) 
df['Type'] = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]

s = df.groupby("Type")['Date'].shift()
df['dt2'] = df['Date'].sub(s).fillna(pd.Timedelta(0)).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
   HH                Date  Type     dt2
0   0 1990-01-01 00:00:00     1     0.0
1   1 1990-01-01 01:00:00     1  3600.0
2   2 1990-01-01 02:00:00     1  3600.0
3   3 1990-01-01 03:00:00     1  3600.0
4   4 1990-01-01 04:00:00     1  3600.0
5   5 1990-01-01 05:00:00     2     0.0
6   6 1990-01-01 06:00:00     2  3600.0
7   7 1990-01-01 07:00:00     2  3600.0
8   8 1990-01-01 08:00:00     2  3600.0
9   9 1990-01-01 09:00:00     2  3600.0
```

Another idea with [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['dt2'] = df.groupby("Type")['Date'].diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(0)).dt.total_seconds()
```